# How to blobless clone in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-git-plugin

I'd like to execute a blobless clone for a Git repository (i.e. `git clone --filter=blob:none <url>`). But looking at the documentation for [`scmGit`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/params/scmgit/)'s `extensions.cloneOption`, it doesn't seem to support specifying a `filter` flag.

Is there any [Git plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/)-native ways to do a blobless clone? Or must I resort to binding credentials (with `withCredentials`) and running `sh` steps?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you solve yours?

Comment: I ended up doing shallow clone, binding the credentials with `withCredentials`, and running `sh 'git fetch --refetch --filter=blob:none --unshallow origin master'` to do a blobless fetch. Also did some experimenting with build times, just doing everything (`init`, `remote add`, `fetch`es etc.) all as `sh` steps was faster than a mix of `checkout` + `sh`. So to answer your question - I just ended up doing a bunch of `sh` steps.